# Properties file and array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, logic

Good afternoon, I have a problem. When reading a property file, and passing it to an array, it looks like the array is repeated until you finish reading the document, as shown in the image

[image: Problem example from console]

I'm supposed to read the properties from a txt file that contains them and pass the artist's name to an array of size 10.

Here the methods used by the program

```
/**
 * Carga la información inicial del karaoke.
 */
private void cargarKaraoke() {

    try {

        Properties datos = new Properties();

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(RUTA_ARCHIVO);

        datos.load(in);

        in.close();

        int numArtistas = Integer.parseInt(datos.getProperty("total.artistas"));

        for(int i = 1; i <= numArtistas; i++) {

            String nombre = datos.getProperty("artista" + i + ".nombre");

            String categoria = datos.getProperty("artista" + i + ".categoria");

            String imagen = datos.getProperty("artista" + i + ".imagen");

            karaoke.agregarArtista(nombre, categoria, imagen);

            int numCanciones = Integer.parseInt(datos.getProperty("artista" 
                    + i + ".total.canciones"));

            for(int j = 1; j <= numCanciones; j++) {
                String cancion = datos.getProperty("artista" + i + ".cancion" 
                        + j + ".nombre");
                int duracion = Integer.parseInt(datos.getProperty("artista" 
                        + i + ".cancion" + j + ".duracion"));
                String letra = datos.getProperty("artista" + i + ".cancion" 
                        + j + ".letra");
                int dificultad = Integer.parseInt(datos.getProperty( "artista" 
                        + i + ".cancion" + j + ".dificultad"));
                String genero = datos.getProperty("artista" + i + ".cancion" 
                        + j + ".genero");
                String ruta = datos.getProperty("artista" + i + ".cancion" 
                        + j + ".ruta");

                karaoke.agregarCancion(nombre, cancion, duracion, letra, 
                        dificultad, genero, ruta);

            }

        }

    }

    catch(Exception e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No fue posible cargar la información "
                + "inicial del karaoke " + e.getMessage(), "Error", 
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

    }

}

    public void agregarArtista(String nombreArtista, String categoria, String imagen) {

    for (int i = 0; i < artistas.length; i++) {

        artistas[i] = new Artista(nombreArtista, categoria, imagen);

    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(artistas));

}

    public int agregarCancion(String nombre, int duracion, String letra, int dificultad, 
        String genero, String ruta) {

    canciones.add(new Cancion(dificultad, duracion, genero, nombre, letra, ruta));

    return 1;

}
```

But at the time of testing the results of the image appear.

Personally I think the problem is in the method to add artist, but I can not identify the problem.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

Comment: If you were to (try to) describe, in words, what `agregarArtista` (as it's currently written) does, what would you say? How would you describe what you **want** it to do? It almost certainly doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: The only thing I want you to do is add the names of the artists to the targeted arrangement. For example my property file has the artists: AC/DC, Adele, Run DMC, ..., to complete 10 artists.
You should save in my arrangement in position 1, AC / DC, in position 2, Adele, ..., so successive until finished. But I can not get it done that way, any suggestions?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can save all Artista obejcts in a List `List<Artista> artistas = new ArrayList<Artista>()` and change the Method `agregarArtista` to fill the list with the Artists Data:

```
public void agregarArtista(String nombreArtista, String categoria, String imagen) {
    artistas.add(new Artista(nombreArtista, categoria, imagen));
    System.out.println(artistas);

}
```

If You want only first 10 Artists then You could change the Method as below:

```
    public void agregarArtista(String nombreArtista, String categoria, String imagen) {
        if (artistas.size() < 10) {
            artistas.add(new Artista(nombreArtista, categoria, imagen));
        }
        System.out.println(artistas);
    }
```

If the result should be in a Array then You could convert List to an Array like this: 
`Artista[] artistasArray = artistas.toArray(new Artista[0]);`

Comment: Thank you is not repeated but now only shows me the final artist, in the list. View image: http://subefotos.com/ver/?4ae3228af0ab4ed3fa4c5ecfb42a7a3ao.png

Comment: If it is of any use, these are my teacher's instructions for the method's functionality:
Find the end of the artist arrangement and add the new artist to that position

Comment: Ok and how you add Artists names to the ComboBox? From the artistasArray? Are on this List all data that You Need? Do you convert the List to an Array? Your Question was how to eliminate repeated data :)

Comment: With a separate method I create an aaraylist with the contents of the previously created array and pass the arraylist as parameter and by means of a forleo the content and do a casting to convert the contents of the list to an object of class Artista

Comment: @luisfelipe if the Artist Data are ok in the ArrayList in agregarArtista, then you must check the other Methods that prepare the data for ComboBox Model.

Comment: I checked the method addArtist that you explained to me before and it returns to me that the array is of length 1, that is why I do not return more artists, Is there any other way to turn an arraylist into an array?

Comment: Yes, you could do it in a loop. First create an empty Array of Artista objects with length that is equal to List size. In the second step you must iterate through that new Array and set its elements like this `artistaNewArray[i] = artistas.get(i)`; It is the simple way to do it.

Comment: You could try to change the `Artista[] artistasArray = artistas.toArray(new Artista[0]);` to `Artista[] artistasArray = artistas.toArray(new Artista[artistas.size()]);` maybe this part was wrong - it creates new array of length = 1.

Comment: It does not work, checking the code more thoroughly. It is because the arraylist only stores an artist, not yet because, but there is no way to work directly with the array and meet the requirements, put by my teacher. Since I do not understand the part of: Look for the end of the artist arrangement and add the new artist in that position, I do not know what he means by looking at the end of it.

Comment: Maybe you must read the data and then save in the Property File at the position lastArtistIndex +1 your new entered Artist data? You list all data from File abd store to the same File new Artist with new Property key?

Comment: I did not understand that part, could it be a bit more clear please, or do you mean to create a new .txt file containing the properties?

Comment: Maybe ypur teacher wants, that you insert into the Properties File at the End new Artist data

Comment: Or you must add new Artist at the End of the Array.